# Listen/subscribe to platform event on experience sites?

Tags: api, lightning-experience, subscriber

I have tried [lightning-emp-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) but it only works if the component is in the salesforce lightning pages itself, and not in my "homemade" experience sites.

Is there any way I can subscribe to such event on experience sites?

Answer (score 0):

Community users don't have access to Push Topics and Platform Event, Data Change Event are built on Push Topics.

There is a way to do it  -

you need to download cometd from [cometD](https://download.cometd.org/cometd-3.1.1-distribution.tar.gz)
Extract and upload the cometd.js from the common folder as a static resource.

```
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import cometdlwc from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/cometd";
```

```
connectedCallBack(){
loadScript(this, cometdlwc)
    .then(() => {
        var cometdlib = new window.org.cometd.CometD();
        
//Calling configure method of cometD class, to setup authentication which will be used in handshaking
  cometdlib.configure({
    url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/47.0/',
    requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth ' + this.sessionId}, // you need get the sessionId from Apex
    appendMessageTypeToURL : false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

cometdlib.websocketEnabled = false;

cometdlib.handshake(function(status) {
            
    if (status.successful) {
        // Successfully connected to the server.
        // Now it is possible to subscribe or send messages
        console.log('Successfully connected to server');
        cometdlib.subscribe('/event/PlatformEvent__e', function (message) {
                  console.log('subscribed to message!'+ message);
       });
    } else {
        /// Cannot handshake with the server, alert user.
        console.error('Error in handshaking: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
     }
   });
  }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the answer to warn about CometD constraints; Salesforce limits the number of concurrent CometD subscribers and event deliveries per day as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm).